# React Portal Not Working With A Tooltip Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-portal

I'm trying to use [react-portal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-portal) with my tooltip component. There are no errors, however it does not appear to be working:

1. The tooltip is still partially hidden by its parent container with `overflow:hidden`
2. I do not see it added to a new div outside of `#root`.

```
import { Portal } from 'react-portal';

return (
    <>
      <Wrapper
        onMouseEnter={showTip}
        onMouseLeave={hideTip}
        ref={triggerRef}
      >
        {children}
      </Wrapper>

      {render && (
        <Portal node={triggerRef.current}>
          <Content
            placement={placement}
            fade={active}
          >
            {content}
          </Content>
        </Portal>
      )}
    </>
  );
```

Here's the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-bop8f?file=/src/tooltip.js) for full code.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with react portal , the problem is your style , I made a little change in your portal.js file:

```
  if (typeof window === "object") {
    if (target) {
      root = document.getElementById("root");
    }
    el = document.createElement("div");
    el.setAttribute('style', 'position:relative'); // this line
    el.id = "portal-root";
  }
```

because your tooltip displayed right on your text and
`onMouseLeave` immediately called and tooltip hides again
so in the styled component and in the top case when I changed bottom style:

```
  ${({ placement }) =>
    placement === "top" &&
    css`
      bottom: calc(100% + 50px); // this line
      &::before {
        top: calc(100% - 10px);
      }
    `}
```

and its works:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, your solution is a possibility. I updated my sandbox to use `react-portal` instead of the `portal.js`, in doing so, it throws an error on my code. Would you know why? https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-bop8f?file=/src/tooltip.js

Comment: please check this:  [https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-forked-j3ymq](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-forked-j3ymq?file=/src/portal.js)